# What spaces are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ = $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ = $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$?

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers, products

What spaces are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ =  $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$ =  $\mathbb{Q}^\infty$? (The space of all rational sequences, considered with the standard product topology).

I have found interesting characterization in a paper by Engelen "Characterizations of the countable infinite product of rationals and some related problems" that says:

> Let $X = \{ (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{N}^\omega: lim_{i
> \mapsto \infty} x_i = \infty \}$. Then $X \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\omega$.

I find this interesting and my questions are

1. What are some more "practical" examples of spaces with the condition above?
2. What are other spaces or conditions for spaces being homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Maybe [*On the group of homeomorphisms of the real line that map the pseudoboundary onto itself*](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-2006-022-8) by Jan J. Dijkstra and Jan van Mill (2006; freely available), which I found by googling ["Engelen" + "product" + "rational" + topological](https://www.google.com/search?q="Engelen"+"product"+"rational"+topological&filter=0) (2nd item I looked at, so other items in this search should be looked at; quotes intentionally left off 'topological'). See the characterizations 2.5 & 2.6 on p. 533 -- probably same as Engelen paper, **(continued)**

Comment: and not particularly useful for examples unless you are very familiar with all the concepts, but for some specific examples see the first sentence of Section 3 (p. 533), and 3.3 (p. 534), and 5.1 (p. 541).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you, that is interesting! If you dont want to make separate answer, I may use your sources and summarize your comments and my thoughts into an answer (if you dont mind.)

Comment: It would be useful to specify the topology you are using on your spaces.

Comment: I don't mind. I just googled the paper's title, which led me to [this online copy](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/701878/WSAA_13-1985-2_6.pdf). After glancing over the paper, I chose what I thought were reasonable keywords -- not too many, to avoid leaving out something relevant. I put quotes around three of the words, because I assumed anything relevant would use the exact spelling of those words. I didn't put quotes around 'topological' (for "topological product", but I was afraid this phrase might be too restrictive) to include cognates such as 'topology', 'topologies', etc.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thanks for pointing out, added a note. I want it in the standard product topology. (I think with other topologies $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ can even have a different name, such as Erdos space..?) If you have seen $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ with different topology, please let me know, I always work with the product one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have so far discovered four types of spaces homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. (Thanks for useful sources that @Dave L. Renfo provided in his comments).

1. Paper: Characterizations of the countable infinite product of rationals and some related problems, author: Engelen (sorry I didnt find an online link, I have access via my university).

> Let $X = \{ (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{N}^\omega: lim_{i
> \mapsto \infty} x_i = \infty \}$. Then $X \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$.

2. Paper:
   [On the Group of Homeomorphisms of the Real Line That Map the Pseudoboundary Onto Itself](https://www-cambridge-org.ezproxy.is.cuni.cz/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-the-group-of-homeomorphisms-of-the-real-line-that-map-the-pseudoboundary-onto-itself/B52FFF0B9137A0F86E7C691469888904)

> If $A$ is any countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $H(\mathbb{R} | A)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. (Where $H(\mathbb{R} | A)$ denotes the
> subgroup of $A$, $\{ f \in H(X) : f(A) = A\}$.

3. From the same paper as 2):

> $H(C | D)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. (Where $C$
> stands for the Cantor set and $D$ is its countable dense subgroup).

4. Paper: [Countable products of zero-dimensional absolute Fσδ spaces](https://core.ac.uk/display/202082359)

> For every zero-dimensional $F_{\sigma \delta}$-space $X$, we have $X \times \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$.

5. Paper: The same as 5)

> Let $X$ be a non-empty closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$. Then $X \times \mathbb{Q}^\omega \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\omega$.

6. The same paper as 4), 5)

> Let $\{X_i: i \in \mathbb{N}\}$, $\{Y_i: i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be
> families of non-empty, zero-dimensional absolute $F_{\sigma
>  \delta}$-spaces which are not complete, and suppose that
> $\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^\infty Y_i$ are homogeneous.
> If $\prod_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ and $\prod_{i=1}^\infty W_i$ are not
> Baire, then they are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=\exp(z)-1$. The "zero-dimensional remainder" of $\mathbb Q ^\omega$ is homeomorphic to the set of points in the complex plane $z\in \mathbb C$ such that $f^n(z)$ goes to neither $0$ nor $\infty$ https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.13876.pdf. By zero-dimensional remainder, I mean the complement of a dense copy of $\mathbb Q ^\omega$ in a complete zero-dimensional space. For example, $\mathbb P ^\omega\setminus (\mathbb Q+\pi)^\omega$. I am unaware of a copy of $\mathbb Q ^\omega$ that is generated very simply in this manner, in complex dynamics.